# Android Proguard configuration for the v7 Support Library ActionBar

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library

I'm using the v7 Support Library to show an [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) on Android 2.x. It works well enough but I had to fix a few class/method not found errors after enabling Proguard.

Are there any guidelines on which classes need to be preserved?

So far I have these:

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView
```

It seems to work now but I'm not that confident that it won't crash at some stage because of some other supposedly internal class referenced in some XML file.

Answer (score 52):

I solved it with:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: Where did you get it from? does google have this anywhere? Does the "**" mean all files and subfolders, recursively? What's the part inside the "{}" (sorry I don't remember) ?

Comment: They don't use it? That's weird.

Comment: This is not recommended. It will keep all library classes, even those you don't need. See http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 4):

I use this, somewhat similar to what the v4 version suggested:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
```

Comment: Where did you find that suggestion for v4?

Comment: Well, I can't recall. If you Google for it, you'll find quite a few references, including here on SO. Maybe it wasn't officially suggested anywhere, I don't know, but it's rather logical and it works, too. :-)

Comment: Adding these two lines without "internal" (e.g. android.support.v7.**) solved my problem. Similarly I added these lines for v4.

Comment: For anyone using the EasyShare widget (or any other widgets) you will probably want to add this too:
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }

Answer (score 0):

I got it from [Android Proguard Snippet](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-support-v7-appcompat.pro)

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

Hope it will work.