# Android application crashes after proguard

Tags: android, proguard

Application crashes after proguard (proguard generated by eclipse IDE).

logcat stacktrace

```
W/SupportMenuInflater(13657): Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
W/SupportMenuInflater(13657): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
W/SupportMenuInflater(13657):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(13657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(13657): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(13657):    at com.mypack.app.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(13657):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)`
```

default version of proguard.cfg file

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

`

**EDIT**: to resolve the problem you need to add this lines to proguard.cfg and have no errors. New lines tells proguard to ignore android.support libraries.

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: can you post proguard.cfg?

Comment: this is my proguard-android.txt http://pastebin.com/icLNnUxM

Comment: Sorry can't access pastebin due to proxy restriction, but nateZor's answer looks like the first thing to check in this case.

Comment: please look at this http://pastie.org/8725071

Comment: Can you add it to your your original post?

Comment: added produard to original post

Comment: My problem :java.lang.NullPointerException in onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your proguard config, you have commented out the keep of the class that it can't find:

```
#-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider
```

Did you try uncommenting that and building again?

EDIT: since that didn't solve your problem, maybe try the catch all described here:

[Android Proguard configuration for the v7 Support Library ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290108/android-proguard-configuration-for-the-v7-support-library-actionbar)

specifically, try adding:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

You can then make it more specific if that works, because this obviously just keeps all the support library classes, even ones you don't use.

Comment: I tried to uncomment this line but the same problem appears

Comment: thank's, the problem was solved, I added solution in original post,  just ignored support libraries from proguard