# In Android app when minifyEnabled true my FAB doesn't animate up to make room for snackbar

Tags: android, android-proguard

In my Android app (using Android Studio) I'm using com.android.support:design:22.2.0 for a floating action button, and for a snackbar.

When building my app while minifyEnabled is false the FAB animates upwards and downwards with the appearance and dismissal of my snackbar as expected (as far as I know on every supported Android version). However, when built with minifyEnabled true and ran on a device with an API version of 21 or below the FAB is not animated, but rather covers or is covered by the snackbar, depending on the Android version.

My proguard rules are the defaults, where proguard-rules.pro is only populated by comments.

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Any insight into why this might be happening would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200571/863753 I have fixed this issue by adding the following to my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
    -keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
    -keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
```

Comment: and inspired by your answer i have fixed my issue :) i been scratching my head for like 4 hours on this