# Proguard Hell - Can't find referenced class error

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I have just finished my first app. And once I turned on MinifyEnabled to true

I got this error when I try to release

Is there a short way where I can remove all these warning and errors?

```
Warning: io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning: kotlin.dom.EventListenerHandler: can't find superclass or interface org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener
Warning: com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.path.parser.SvgToPath: can't find referenced class org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser
Warning: com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.path.parser.SvgToPath: can't find referenced class org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.ClassMetaData: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Filer
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Filer
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning: io.realm.processor.DefaultModuleGenerator: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
```

Comment: it seems proguard stripped these files while it is being used somewhere in your app.

Comment: Follow these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199527/android-studio-1-0-2-minifyenabled-true-crashes-the-signed-release-apk and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589318/error-building-apk-when-minifyenabled-true. I think you have to make combination of `--keep` and `--dontwarn` according to your logs