# Action Share Button works on debug mode but does not work on release mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"  />
    </menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        // Get its ShareActionProvider
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)            MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);

    // Connect the dots: give the ShareActionProvider its Share Intent
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent());
        }
        return true;
    }
private Intent mShareIntent() {
        Intent mShareIntent = new Intent();
        mShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.qwe");
        return mShareIntent;

   }
```

**ToolBar code in Fragment**

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Gradle file**

```
        android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.zapz.android.quizy"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
```

SHARE BUTTON appears as text[SHARE] in release mode but in debug mode its working fine with share icon appearing on the toolbar.

 Im using a toolbar and not action bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android crash application after proguard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712702/android-crash-application-after-proguard)