# Deployed react native app crashes when downloaded from google play store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I just deployed my first react native app to the google play store but the app crashes when i install it from the store.

I have tried multiple options to trace where the issues is coming from and i still don’t have an idea what could be causing it.

The app works fine when i run on a simulator or real device and when i build .apk from the expo server it also works fine without crash.

So i think maybe the issue is with the .aab version that was uploaded to the store. Please i really need your help. Thanks in advance.

Below is the crash report from google play console

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{bb9e4f0 u0a190 RCVR bg:+2m7s706ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4035)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1924)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{bb9e4f0 u0a190 RCVR bg:+2m7s706ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1715)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1670)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:720)
at alj.a (PG:2)
at alm.a (PG:3)
at wnv.a (PG:2)
at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.onReceive (PG:6)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4026)
```

Comment: Share your crash logs. If you enable firebase crash reports get the logs or Goto play store console to get the crash reports

Comment: I just updated my question with the crash report

Comment: debug your app in android studios logcat, it will show you proper error.

Comment: I’m using expo cli for development

Comment: I get the same error log with a flutter app .aab I uploaded to the Google Play Store. https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/not-allowed-to-start-service-intent/730141 This person seems to have the same error. What SDK version are you using, and what android version is your device on?

Comment: I think the issue is with generating the aab file because when i decompile to apk with bundletool and install directly app still crashes but direct apk build works fine

Comment: I’m using sdk version 46 and i have installed on android 9 and 10

Comment: Are you use the proguard? if yes try to fix the proguard issues or remove proguard

Comment: @Ranjithkumar you mean i should delete all proguard rules?

Comment: you can remove or specify which class you no need to be proguard. if you want to keep proguard refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712702/android-application-crashes-after-proguard

Comment: But is it Safe to totally delete proguard ?