# chromecast button not showing up after proguard configuration

Tags: android, android-layout, proguard, chromecast

After configuring progaurd, chromecast button doesn't show up and instead text like "PLAY ON.." appears in the Action bar.[image]
I have tried adding below line in config file but no luck

```
-keep class com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.** {*;}
```

please let me know if i am missing anything.
 Thanks.

Comment: The cast icon/image is not part of the CCL, it is part of the media router library. Try what is posted here and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24935165/2765813

Comment: @AliNaddaf Yes my bad, I forgot to keep v7 support libs, it worked fine after including "-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }" in config file. Thx for suggestion :)