# res not found: android:drawable/ic_ab_back_material with resource ID

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am getting this error only in release version, the debug version works fine. Resource item is not found, @android:drawable/ic_ab_back_material with resource ID

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.k.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at in.reweyou.reweyouforums.ForumMainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
                                                                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:drawable/ic_ab_back_material with resource ID #0x1080313
                                                                           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f06000a
```

My proguard file:

```
-dontwarn io.nlopez.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn **

-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
-printmapping obfuscation/mapping.txt


# glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide code work you have so far.

Comment: the debug version runs fine, i am not able to understand why release version fails(minifyenabled true)

Comment: Please add your proguard file

Comment: added my proguard file

Comment: on what android version are you testing  ?

Comment: You are missing supportv7 ones https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935165/2308683

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF Nougat...but its failing on every version

Comment: @cricket_007 do i have to write keep for toolbar class?

Comment: In the stacktrace, see `at android.support.v7.app.k.b`? You are squashing the support library. Your XML needs the support library's full names

Comment: @cricket_007 may be this will work, but keeping all support lib files isnt a good idea. The release was working fine a few days back, but i dont remember what changes leads to this crash

Comment: You should check if the resource is present in only debug folder and not main and release folder